# clEnqueueWriteImage returns -5

Tags: c++, opencl

If I try to upload data to image buffer the function `clEnqueueWriteImage` returns `-5`. That error isn't specified inside OpenCL specification. What is the problem? The command queue, memory object and data looks great. Blocking is set to `true`.

My C++ code look like this:

```
m_NativeImage = clCreateImage2D(_rContext, _MemoryFlag, &m_NativeImageFormat, m_Width, m_Height, 0, NULL, &Error);

size_t Origin[] = {0,0,0};        
size_t Region[] = {m_Width, m_Height, 1}; // Size of object to be transferred

Error = clEnqueueWriteImage(m_NativeCommandQueue, m_NativeImage, _Blocking, Origin, Region, 0, 0, _pData, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: -5 means CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES, what's the size of your image, what's the format, how is _pData defined? I'm guessing packing error.

Comment: The picture is an 546x546 BMP file (874KB). I loaded this file into a unsigned char* array (_pData is void*). Is it possible that the format of a picture has to be a power of 2?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It was a problem of my declared image format. I used `CL_UNORM_INT8` but it has to be `CL_UNORM_SHORT_565`. Thanks for your help!

Watch this: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_image_format.html